# Botón en un email que haga "reply all" con un mensaje

Tags: html, macros, vb, outlook

Muy buenas.

Estoy intentando hacer se mande un Email de Outlook, pero este correo debe tener un botón que haga un "Reply All".

De momento he conseguido que se haga "Reply All" con una macro, pero esta lo hace con los correos que tienes seleccionados. Esta es la Macro que conseguí encontrar:

```
Sub ReplyAll()

    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
    Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
            olReply.HTMLBody = "Hello, Thank you. " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
        olReply.Display
        olReply.Send
    Next olItem
End Sub
```

Lo que me interesaría es corregir esa macro, para que solo mande el Mail desde el que se pulsa el botón, el botón debería estar ubicado en el cuerpo del mensaje.

Como nota adicional, también me gustaría preguntar, como introducir esa macro en el susodicho botón para que esta funcione con pulsarlo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos.

P.D. Disculpad, soy bastante novel en esto de VB y HTML.

21/08/2020 P.D.2 Espero que lo que he añadido sea suficiente para encontrar la solución. Muchas gracias por las recomendaciones para editar el mensaje.

Comment: Y bien, ¿cuál es la macro en cuestión? dónde aparecería este botón que mencionas? EL contenido actual de la pregunta sólo permite adivinar y esa no es la idea. Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade la info correspondiente para que todos puedan ayudarte más fácil

Comment: Ok, gracias por las recomendaciones, ahora edito la pregunta.